# How can I make array B from array A without infinities included in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, arrays, find, infinity

Array A looks like this:
[1, -inf, 2, 3, inf, -60.2]

Array B should look like this:
[1, 2, 3, -60.2]

How can I make array B from array A without infinities included in Python 2.7?

Comment: Thank you all! This problem is now solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B = filter(lambda x: abs(x) != float('inf'), A)
```

Comment: +1 List comprehension is probably faster, but that's the idea. Storing `float('inf')` in a variable might be useful too.

Comment: Thanks! Also, how to make an array C with indices of non-infinite numbers of A: [0, 2, 3, 5]?

Comment: for your second question, something like [i for i, el in enumerate(A) if abs(el) != float('inf')]

Answer (score 6):

```
B = [x for x in A if not math.isinf(x)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean:

```
>>> inf = float('inf');
>>> import math
>>> print filter(lambda x: not math.isinf(x), [1, -inf, 2, 3, inf, -60.2])
[1, 2, 3, -60.200000000000003]
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest one:

```
arrayA = [1, float('-inf'), 2, 3, float('inf'), -60.2]
arrayB = []
for item in arrayA:
    if item != float('inf') and item != float('-inf'):
        arrayB.append(item)
```

Not a one-line solution, but clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can define inf by

```
inf = 1e400
```