# How can I make array C with the indices of non-infinite numbers of array A in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, arrays, find, infinity

Array A looks like this:

```
[1, -inf, 2, 3, inf, -60.2]
```

Array C should look like this:

```
[0, 2, 3, 5]
```

How can I make array C with the indices of non-infinite numbers of array A in Python 2.7?

Comment: This comes very close to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841837/how-can-i-make-array-b-from-array-a-without-infinities-included-in-python-2-7). Tip: Have a look at `enumerate`.

Answer (score 4):

```
inf = float('inf')
a = [1, -inf, 2, 3, inf, -60.2]
c = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if abs(v) != inf]
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "array" you mean "numpy array":

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: a = np.array([1, -np.inf, 2, 3, np.inf, -60.2])

In [14]: np.where(~np.isinf(a))[0]
Out[14]: array([0, 2, 3, 5])
```